# php object into javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php

I'm just trying to convert this `php` object into `javascript` multidimensional array but it keeps on getting this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in line 3.

I really need your help. I can't move an inch with my codes. Thank you.

```
<?php 
    $phpArray = Array ( [0] => 
        Array ( [0] => January [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => February [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => March [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [3] => Array ( [0] => April [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [4] => Array ( [0] => May [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [5] => Array ( [0] => June [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [6] => Array ( [0] => July [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [7] => Array ( [0] => August [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [8] => Array ( [0] => September [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [9] => Array ( [0] => October [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [10] => Array ( [0] => November [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) )
        [11] => Array ( [0] => December [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Medical [1] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Financial [1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Burial [1] => 2 ) ) ) );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;

    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        alert(jArray[i]);
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: That's not a PHP object. What you've got there is a string representation of a PHP array (from the output of `print_r()` by the look of it). You'll need the actual array in order to run it through `json_encode()`

Comment: Do you need a one time static conversion? ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will do you any good or what you plan with it, but here is the php array derived from that dump in your post.

```
<?php
$phparray = array(0 => array(
        0 => "January",
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => "Medical",
                1 => 12
            ),
            1 => array(
                0 => "Financial",
                1 => 13
            ),
            2 => array(
                0 => "Burial",
                1 => 12
            ),
            3 => array(
                0 => "Financial",
                1 => 1
            ),
            4 => array(
                0 => "Burial",
                1 => 2
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => "February",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        2 => array(
            0 => "March",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        3 => array(
            0 => "April",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        4 => array(
            0 => "May",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        5 => array(
            0 => "June",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        6 => array(
            0 => "July",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        7 => array(
            0 => "August",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        8 => array(
            0 => "September",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        9 => array(
            0 => "October",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        10 => array(
            0 => "November",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        ),
        11 => array(
            0 => "December",
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => "Medical",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                1 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 13
                ),
                2 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 12
                ),
                3 => array(
                    0 => "Financial",
                    1 => 1
                ),
                4 => array(
                    0 => "Burial",
                    1 => 2
                )
            )
        )
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, you will need to put quotes around the values you are trying to insert:

```
<?php 
    $phpArray = 
    Array ( [0] => 
        Array ( [0] => January, [1] => 
                   // ^^ This needs quotes!
                   // You also need to put a comma after each element.
            Array ( [0] => 
                Array ( [0] => Medical, [1] => 12 )
```

To put string values inside an array, you need to put them inside quotes (assuming they are not constants - which I would doubt.

```
Array ( [0] => 'Medical', [1] => 12 )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => "Medical", [1] => 12 )
```

or

```
$var='Medical';
$something=Array ( [0] => $var, [1] => 12 ) ;
```

Comment: It needs more than just quotes.

Comment: @scrowler This is true, but with quotes, the parse error should be solved - assuming the right number of close brackets are there - which I am not going to check :)

Comment: @scrowler LMAO< yes. Indeedy. I need coffee... +1

Comment: @user3642976 Also scrowler pointed out that I totally missed the fact you have no commas in your statement, which I have edited my answer for.

Comment: @user3642976 your "array" is the output of a print_r function, I was going to convert it back manually for you but it's way too long for me to be bothered. What you need to do is get the **original** PHP array, not the output from it. Did you copy and paste that data from somewhere? Get it from the source.

Comment: yes i copied it from the returned print_r of the php array. how can i convert it to its original php array? is there a way please?